# MindMapping with LaTeX

Tags: graphics, mindmaps

Is there any [mind mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map) tool which will allow for typing in LaTeX?
I particularly like [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) but it has no LaTeX support.

Comment: Check the [PGF manual Section 39](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) for a nice option.

Comment: According to http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FreeMind there is lisp lib to convert from FreeMind to Org-mode, and since Org-mode has LaTeX export you should be able to get LaTeX output in the end.

Answer (score 17):

TikZ provides a `mindmapping` library for that purpose. Examples:

- [Computer science mindmap](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-science-mindmap/)
- [Scientific interactions](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/scientific-interactions/) by Andrei Sobolevski:

[image]

Comment: It looks good but I couldn't find a GUI for making the mindmap. I'd really appreciate having a GUI for creating the mindmap (Point-Click-Write-Connect)

Comment: @Nunoxic: That's not what `TikZ` is about... if you need that kind of facility, this is the wrong place to look for. You may try Inkscape -> export to TikZ, but I guess that's quite complicated.

Comment: There is Tikzedt GUI for tikz. But it is a semi graphical editor. But it is useful for me at least. But (Point-Click-Write-Connect) ! It is difficult.

Comment: @Harish Kumar Souldn't this be TieZEdt (TiedZed ist ein Zeichen Editor)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Xmind](https://www.xmind.net/) application to serve your purpose. It will allow you to type in latex. The app is very simple to use. You may use it on Android, Windows, macOS, iOS/iPadOS, Linux, and Web. However, you will have to subscribe for six months or one year to use the latex feature.

The latex commands that XMind supports can be found below:

https://www.xmind.net/faq/question/equation/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).